# Databinding: A ViewModel should not have a reference to the views, but...?

Tags: android, xml, mvvm, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

### Prerequisites

So yes, there are a lot of similar questions, but I couldn't find an answer to this specific one: Obviously it is best practive to not let the viewModel hold any references to Android framework classes, and also views. **But!**

If I use data binding, I can have a xml layout that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="SomeViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/myButtpn"
            style="@style/mybuttonStyle"
            android:onClick="@{viewModel::onButtonClicked}"/>
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Now this expects to find a method like this in my `SomeViewModel`:

```
fun onButtonclicked(view: View) {
    // I don't need the parameter, but Android needs it to be there
}
```

But I could also reference my method like this in the layout:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onButtonClicked()}"
```

and now my method in the viewModel doesn't need to take a view:

```
fun onButtonclicked() {
    // all fine
}
```

### The actual question(s):

Does it actually make a difference? Obviously, I am presenting the viewModel views as function parameters, that then get ignored, so this doesn't look great and seems a bit wasteful. But at no time the viewModel holds any reference to them, in my understanding. So is this bad in any way?

On the other hand, putting this lambda into the xml doesn't look so sexy, but it seems to be the typical practice. Does it have any (Dis-)Advantages?

And third: Would there be any difference between the two approaches in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Does it actually make a difference? Obviously, I am presenting the viewModel views as function parameters, that then get ignored, so this doesn't look great and seems a bit wasteful. But at no time the viewModel holds any reference to them, in my understanding. So is this bad in any way?
```

One of the biggest reason you don't want your ViewModel to hold onto references to Views is because your `ViewModel` outlives the lifecycle of your `Fragment`. Now you have memory leaks.

Also, `ViewModel`(s) in general should be used to expose public values that, in turn, drive the UI to update and layout as specified in many MVVM patterns.

Essentially, `databinding` allows you to do this by removing all of the boilerplate code necessary to bind these items to `Views` in the Fragment. You will see that Android generates `databinding` classes that does exactly this.

```
On the other hand, putting this lambda into the xml doesn't look so sexy, but it seems to be the typical practice. Doies it have any (Dis-)Advantages?
```

There are no disadvantages other than build time performance. Since now that you have these `databinding` code generation, you are generating alot more code during build time as you switch things around in your current module.

It's not a matter of not looking sexy or not, it's to reduce the boilerplate code to bind the `ViewModel` to your Views. If you don't do this in your `xml`, you will do this in your `Fragment` or `Activity`. It's literally the same thing.

```
And third: Would there be any difference between the two approaches in terms of performance?
```

I am assuming runtime performance? No, there are not benefits nor downsides whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I am aware of the reasoning behind why a ViewModel shouldn't hold view references. 
But to clarify: If my ViewModel has a method `myMethod(view: View) {}`but I ignore the view parameter, does then my ViewModel have a reference to that view passed in? I don't think so. It would only hold a reference if I store any view in a field inside the viewModel, in my opinion, and just having "forbidden values" as parameters of the ViewModel's methods poses no danger, as this doesn't interfere with the different lifecycles. No?

Comment: You are 100% correct, there is no danger whatsoever as it would just be local reference within your ViewModel and is exactly the same as doing the `setOnClickListener` within your Fragment and immediately calling the `ViewModel` function. 

It's just syntactic sugar, and you aren't doing anything wrong if you are calling it from your XML. You will see that the generated binding class is doing exactly that. Calling your ViewModel immediately after the onClick call.